# Rounding javascript variable

Tags: javascript, mootools, rounding

Im attempting to round a few variables to 2 decimal places but am having issues

When i use the toFixed() on just the totalprice variable it works find (obviously shipping doesnt round) but when I have it like below (.toFixed on shipping var) javascript console gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 219.863.80 has no method 'toFixed'
updatePriceshg-buy.html:398
(anonymous function)hg-buy.html:436
onchangehg
```

219.86 is the value of price, 63.80 is the price of shipping so it looks like it is concatenating but i cannot work out how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

**Code Below**

```
function updatePrices() {
var price = $('select_1').getValue();
var shipping = $('shippingValue').getValue();
var quantity = $('select_3').getValue();
var totalshipping = (shipping * quantity).toFixed(2);

var totalprice = ((price * quantity)+(totalshipping)).toFixed(2);

$('unitprice').setText(price);
$('shipping').setText(totalshipping);
$('totalprice').setText(totalprice);
}
```

Comment: I have been down _THAT_ road before. Doing a coherent shopping basket based upon DOM values and money is NOT a good idea, it won't scale well. every redesign you do = break. Introduce a new currency = break. Introduce vouchers = break. Introduce carbon offset = break. Try to separate your basket logic from it's visual representation and build a small class with some methods like: `getBasket` (reads cookie or session data and stores them as local objects / numbers), `addToBasket`, `removeFromBasket`, `updateBasket` and finally, `outputBasket` to export it back to the DOM / and or form elements.

Comment: the other thing you don't want to do is pass values computed clientside to your server. pass id references. ids of products -> db lookup -> prices. ids of shipping methods -> cost. eg of a failed checkout is say, freeparking.co.uk where domain renewals are often of 2 years or more, defined by a dropdown with no. of years. using firebug to change the dropdown values, you can renew your domain for 1 year only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var totalshipping = (parseFloat(shipping) * parseFloat(quantity)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: The classic mistake: `getValue` returns a string, and not a number.  And `+` concatenates two strings: `'string' + 'string' = 'stringstring';`...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using some library for handling decimal values properly otherwise you may end up losing some cents here and there. (Of course this is only necessary if you care about those cents.)

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library).